# how to compare two list objects in fluent LINQ

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists which have different type of objects

```
List<Type1> list1
List<Type2> list2
```

The only common things between Type1 and Type2 is the Id property and the Date property.

How do I get a list of Items that have both the ID and the Date property equal to each other?

```
var list3 = list1.where(x=>x.id == ??
```

Thanks

Comment: create a common interface (or base class).

Comment: ...and then use `Join()`

Comment: See my answer for the example or code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join on multiple fields, but you'll need something else to store their values in.

Assuming the other properties are all different between `Type1` and `Type2`, you'll need a third class that stores the information you want to keep.

```
var results
    = (from l1 in list1
       join l2 in list2 on new { l1.ID, l1.Date} equals new { l2.ID, l2.Date }
       select new SomeThirdClass { });
```

Comment: how would you write this in the fluent syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use extension methods, you can just use the .Join() method.

```
var combination = list1.Join(list2, 
    l1 => new { l1.Id, l1.Date }, 
    l2 => new { l2.Id, l2.Date }, 
    (l1, l2) => Tuple.Create(l1, l2));
```

Comment: @agarwaen - Likewise.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common base class or Interface and implement the IEqualityComparer for it.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id;
    public DateTime Date;
}

class Type1: BaseClass
{


}

class Type2 : BaseClass
{


}

public class BaseClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<BaseClass>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<BaseClass> Members

    public bool Equals( BaseClass x, BaseClass y )
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Date == y.Date;
    }

    public int GetHashCode( BaseClass obj )
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode ();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then simply use Intersect() and the Comparer to create a merge list with distinct objects.

```
List<Type1> t1 = new List<Type1>();
List<Type2> t2 = new List<Type2>();
var combined = t1.Intersect( t2, new BaseClassComparer() );
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `.Intersect` instead of `.Union`?